# How do I find the minimum element in an array of strings, but only considering integers?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, integer, min

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I have an array of strings that are supposed to be integers ...

```
["1", "55", "25", ... ]
```

I have the following for figuring out the minimum number in the array

```
data.map(&:to_i).min
```

This works great, except for the times when a non-integer string creeps into my array, like

```
["1", "a", "2", "3"]
```

With my `data.map(&:to_i).min` line, the above returns zero.  How do I modify my code so that it will only take the min of elements in the array that are actually integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few ways of doing this, but the easiest is to screen out non-numerical values if you want to ignore the garbage:

```
data = ["1", "a", "2", "3"]
data.grep(/\A\-?\d+\z/).map(&:to_i).min
# => 1
```

The [`grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) method makes it pretty easy to pick out things that match a particular pattern, as well as many other things.

Comment: @steenslag It wasn't clear if this data was going to be positive only or not, but in any case I've added an optional `-`.

Answer (score 3):

When I want to convert a string to an integer, if and only it is a string representation of an integer, I always use [Kernel::Integer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer):

```
arr = ["3", "a", "2", "0x01", "0c", "0b11", "0o03", "4", "1_000"]

arr.select { |s| Integer(s) rescue nil }.min_by { |s| Integer(s) }
  #=> "0x01"
```

Here

```
arr.select { |s| Integer(s) rescue nil }
  #=> ["3", "2", "0x01", "0b11", "0o03", "4", "1_000"]
```

Note `"0x01".to_i #=> 0` (not!), which is why `Integer` must be used twice.

If the string is not a representation of an integer, `Integer` raises an exception:

```
Integer("a") 
  #=> ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "a"
```

which is rescued in-line, causing `nil` to be returned, resulting is the string not being selected. (One could of course go the extra mile and use a clause that only rescues `ArguementError` exceptions.)

The question asks for an element of the array (a string) to be returned. If its integer equivalent is desired, you can write:

```
a = arr.map { |s| Integer(s) rescue nil }.compact.min
  #=> 1
```

where

```
arr.map { |s| Integer(s) rescue nil }
  #=> [3, nil, 2, 1, nil, 3, 3, 4, 1_000]
```

Note

```
['a', 'b'].map { |s| Integer(s) rescue nil }.compact.min
  #=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Enumerable#grep_v](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep_v) we can do the following and exclude wordy-strings:

```
 arr = ["1", "a", "2", "3"]
 arr.grep_v(/[a-zA-Z]+/).min_by(&:to_i) #=> "1"
```

Modify the regexp as you feel appropriate.